# An idle video/still frame that seamlessly transitions into a short animation, then back?

Tags: python, video

Putting together an interactive effect for my basement tiki bar using a Pi 3 B+. Total newbie to Python as of this morning, so I apologize for the inevitably dumb questions I'll be asking.

I have a PIR sensor that is working great, and is properly triggering a single audio/video with omxplayer, however I want to be able to go from an all-black screen that seamlessly transitions into an effect video when the sensor is triggered, then go back to that idle all-black screen after the effect video ends.

I planned to make the idle all-black video very long (hour or two) so that there was no risk of it ending while people were in the bar. Ideally, I'd like to be able to re-start this effect at any given time before that idle video file would theoretically end.

Right now my issues are about 1 second or so where we return to the Desktop before the idle file (file1) begins. I'd prefer this be completely seamless during the transition. Alongside that issue, I cannot restart the effect until file1 ends.

This is my current code:

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import os
 
pir = MotionSensor(4)
file1 = "idle.mp4"
file2 = "effect.mp4"
 
while True:
    pir.wait_for_motion()
    print ("Effect Start")
    os.system("omxplayer -o 'local' " + file2)
    pir.wait_for_no_motion()
    print ("Effect End")
    os.system ("omxplayer -o 'local' " + file1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wont be able to write you some code for this as I am working on my own project.

Idea to help you:
Have a variable set to 0 when PIR activates that variable changes to a 1. Change your While statement to an IF statement to play different vids.

If 1 then,
Play Selected Video
Else;
Play Black Video